# How to make one random point bounce up and down and another random point do the same?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have been trying to choose one point make it move up then down and then choose another point.

I could not find any way to choose just one point make it move then choose another point.

I am using blender 4.0.2.

edit:
after a lot of work and many tutorials I managed to make a setup that works for me. if this doesn't work for you I am so sorry for you because there are  no tutorials for this B.S.

[image: well that sure was a fun 3 days I think]

Comment: What is a random point? An existing object, a mesh vertex, something else? How should it bounce? A physics simulation, manual animation, precedural motion? Could you edit your post and provide enough details to allow a proper answer

Comment: just use index + compare node + set position. By this you can move one point. To move a random point, replace index with random integer. To move up and down you can use scene time and map range node.